# Issues with Java Collectors

Tags: java, lambda

I'm getting my hands on lambda (Yeah, too late). I'm trying to convert a List of String into HashMap with the key being the value returned by toString() and the value is the original String object.

```
List<String> metas = new ArrayList<String>();
metas.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(String::toString), Function.identity());
```

I'm getting "The type String does not define toString(T) that is applicable here". The reference document for Collectors.toMap() also invokes a method without any parameter as shown here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-

So why does my program says it doesn't define toString(T)?

Comment: Huh? Why on earth would you call `String::toString`? And how is it different from `Function.identity()`?

Comment: You have a closing parenthesis in the wrong place btw.

Comment: @shmosel like I said, just experimenting. it's a correct lambda expression yeah? I'll fix the parenthesis.

Comment: With the correct parens, you're good and the program should work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collectors.toMap` requires at least two parameters, one which maps your stream elements to map entry keys and one which maps them to the corresponding map entry value.

Probably you got the the parentheses wrong. They should look like this:

```
metas.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(String::toString, Function.identity()));
```

The message you got arises from the situation that you are calling `Collectors.toMap` with the single parameter `String::toString`. The type of lambda expressions or method references are inferred by the context they are used in but in this case there is no method `toMap` which could receive a single parameter one could derive the type from. In conclusion the type inferrer seems to drop the whole context and only sees the generic `toMap` method and performs a partial matching of its signatures. It finds a generic key mapper there (function receiving values of unknown generic type T returning some other type). Unfortunately `String::toString` is not of this inferred type (as it can only be interpreted as function receiving a `String` but not any type `T`).

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this?

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("12absc", "2bbds", "abc"));
    Map<String, String> stringStringMap = list.stream()
                                              .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> s));
    System.out.println(stringStringMap);
}
```

Output:

```
{abc=abc, 12absc=12absc, 2bbds=2bbds}
```

To avoid **duplicated** key problem, you can also add [*merge function*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) as:

```
    list.add("12absc");
    stringStringMap = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> s, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue));
    System.out.println(stringStringMap);
```

Output will be the same:

```
{abc=abc, 12absc=12absc, 2bbds=2bbds}
```

Comment: this would also work. but like shmosel and Petr pointed out, fixing the paranthesis worked.